# Jquery default div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to display information on my site with a drop down menu to select the content of a div.

Here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        target = $(this).val();
        $(".result").hide();
        if(target != 'none'){
            $("#" + target).show();
        }

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

and here is my HTML:

```
  <select id="select">
   <option value="op1">R1100R/GS/RT/RS</option>
   <option value="op2">R1100S</option>
   <option value="op3">R1150R/GS/RT/RS</option>
   <option value="op4">R1200R/GS/RS/ST</option>
   <option value="op5">R1200RT</option>
   <option value="op6">R1200C</option>
   <option value="op7">K100/1100</option>
   <option value="op8">K1200RS/GT pre-2005</option>
   <option value="op9">K1200GT</option>
   <option value="op10">K1200R/S</option>
  </select>

  <div id="result">
        <div id="op1" class="result">
        R1100R/GS/RT/RS
        </div>

        <div id="op2" class="result">
        R1100S
        </div>

        <div id="op3" class="result">
        R1150R/GS/RT/RS
        </div>
```

It works fine except when you first load the page all the content is displayed.

I don't want anything displayed until an option is selected.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So hide divs: `.result { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results to start off hidden, add the following rule to your CSS:

```
.result {
    display: none;
}
```

Your jQuery code will override the rule for each individual div when it runs `$("#" + target).show();`.